# How can I solve Sass 'Error: expected more input'

Tags: sass

I'm pretty new to Sass. I'm using version 1.13.0 on a Mac. I'm currently using SCSS on a major project for the first time and I've run into an error I've never seen before. I entered `sass --watch style.scss style.css` into Terminal, as I've done many times in this project without issue. Today however, when I saved my `.scss` file, Sass deleted my `.css` file and gave me the following error:

```
Error: expected more input.

^
style.scss 197:1 root stylesheet

Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
```

Line 197 is the last line in my stylesheet.

`Style.scss` and `style.css.map` remain intact.

I've tried clearing Terminal, quitting and restarting Terminal, and using the standard `sass style.scss style.css` command but that also returned the same error.

Any help? Apologies if I'm leaving out any info. As I mentioned earlier, I'm very new to Sass so please let me know if there's anything else I can clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out my `.scss` file ended in a commend that I had forgotten to close off (I had forgotten to add the final slash in a `/*comment*/`). This was causing the error. Once I closed off the comment, everything went back to working properly.